# Overlapping instances that don't seem to overlap

Tags: haskell, derivingvia

Consider the following (close to minimal) example:

```
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}

class Predicate a where
    test :: a -> Bool

instance (Predicate a, Traversable t) => Predicate (t a) where
    test = all test

data Bar = Bar
instance Predicate Bar where
    test Bar = False

data Baz a = Baz a
instance Predicate a => Predicate (Baz a) where
    test (Baz x) = test x

main :: IO ()
main = print $ test $ Baz Bar
```

Looking at `test $ Baz Bar`, you'd expect a result of `False`, as we have the instances `Predicate Bar` and `Predicate a => Predicate (Baz a)`.

But GHC 8.6.3 and 8.0.1 both reject this:

```
test.hs:18:16: error:
    • Overlapping instances for Predicate (Baz Bar)
        arising from a use of ‘test’
      Matching instances:
        instance (Predicate a, Traversable t) => Predicate (t a)
          -- Defined at test.hs:6:10
        instance Predicate a => Predicate (Baz a)
          -- Defined at test.hs:14:10
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘test $ Baz Bar’
      In the expression: print $ test $ Baz Bar
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ test $ Baz Bar
   |
18 | main = print $ test $ Baz Bar
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And yet there's no overlap: we can confirm there's no instance of `Traversable Baz` by commenting out the `Predicate (Baz a)` instance, in which case we get the error:

```
test.hs:18:16: error:
    • No instance for (Traversable Baz) arising from a use of ‘test’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘test $ Baz Bar’
      In the expression: print $ test $ Baz Bar
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ test $ Baz Bar
   |
18 | main = print $ test $ Baz Bar
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm assuming this is a limitation of `FlexibleInstances`? If so, why, and is there an approved workaround?

---

Okay, turns out this is a consequence of GHC deciding on which instance to use *independently* of the constraints on the instance, as described [here](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick). That trick doesn't seem to work here though:

```
instance (b ~ Baz, Predicate a) => Predicate (b a) where
```

Gives a `Duplicate instance declarations` error, so I'm leaving the question open for a solution that works in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that those instance indeed overlap, since the instance resolution mechanism only looks at the instance head when deciding which instance to take, and only later, *after* an instance has been chosen, it checks the constraints to see that it is met (and otherwise throws and error).

I suggest reading the documentation on [instance resolution](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-declarations)

One way to fix your problem (other than redesigning your solution, which is probably the right thing to do), is to tell GHC that a certain instance is "less important" (or overlappable).
This basically means that GHC will choose a more specific instance if it's available (what more specific means you can read in the documentation linked above).
This is achieved by using the pragma `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` or `{-# OVERLAPS #-}` (read the documentation to see the difference, basically the former is more specific).

The resulting code would look something like this

```
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}

class Predicate a where
    test :: a -> Bool

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Predicate a, Traversable t) => Predicate (t a) where
    test = all test

data Bar = Bar
instance Predicate Bar where
    test Bar = False

data Baz a = Baz a
instance Predicate a => Predicate (Baz a) where
    test (Baz x) = test x

main :: IO ()
main = do
   print . test $ Baz Bar
   print . test $ ([] :: [Bar])
   print . test $ [Bar]
   print . test $ Baz ([] :: [Bar])
```

And the result from running it is

```
False
True
False
True
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With [`DerivingVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html) you can give this behaviour to a newtype

```hs
type    Every :: (k -> Type) -> k -> Type
newtype Every t a = Every (t a)
  deriving
  stock Foldable

-- Foldable is sufficient
instance (Foldable t, Predicate a) => Predicate (Every t a) where
  test :: Every t a -> Bool
  test = all test
```

and derive `Predicate` via it, this is preferable to an overlapping instance like you have given.

```hs
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

type Tree :: Type -> Type
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving
  stock Foldable

  deriving Predicate
  via Every Tree a
```

This opens the possibility for alternative definitions

```
type    Some :: (k -> Type) -> k -> Type
newtype Some t a = Some (t a)
  deriving
  stock Foldable

-- This derives alternative behaviour, here using `any' in lieu of `all' 
instance (Foldable t, Predicate a) => Predicate (Some t a) where
  test :: Some t a -> Bool
  test = any test
```

Just like the [`Ap f a` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) is a better solution than defining instances that are incompatible with `Monoid [a]` and other common instances.

```hs
instance (Applicative f, Semigroup a) => Semigroup (f a) where
  (<>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
  (<>) = liftA2 (<>)

instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => Monoid (f a) where
  mempty :: f a
  mempty = pure mempty
```